# JSON: How to access deep level array

Tags: arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Everything pre-loop is fine. I need help finding the way to access deeper level json. I'm stuck in the "for" loop. The product_name comes out okay in the first loop but nothing deeper than that. I've added some output for each deeper level loop but I don't seem to pass the second one.

[Follow URL](http://www.weber.se/?type=88&pageAlias=lecareglttklinker26&json=1) to view JSON array.

```
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://www.weber.se/?type=88&pageAlias=lecareglttklinker26&json=1';

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    readJson(this.responseText);
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function readJson(response) {
var object = JSON.parse(response);
var output = '<div class="container-fluid">';
        output += '<div class="row">';
            output += '<div class="col-xs-6 text-left"><img src="' + object.product[0].packaging_picture + '" height="230"></div>';
            output += '<div class="col-xs-6 text-right"><img src="' + object.product[0].main_picture + '" height="230"></div>';
        output += '</div>';
        output += '<div class="row">';
            output += '<div>' + object.product[0].standfirst + '</div>';
        output += '</div>';
        output += '<div class="row">';
            output += '<div class="well"><h2>Egenskaper</h2>' + object.product[0].benefits_description + '</div>';
        output += '</div>';

        for (var a = 0; a < object.product.length; a++) {
            var product = object.product[a];
            var name = product.product_name;
            output += '<h2>' + name + '</h2>';
                for (var b = 0; b < product.tabs.length; b++) {
                    var tabs = product.tabs[b];
                    output += 'tabs<br>';
                        for (var c = 0; c < product.tabs.tab.length; c++) {
                            var tab = tabs.tab[c];
                            output += 'tab<br>';
                                for (var d = 0; d < product.tabs.tab.contents.length; d++) {
                                    var contents = tab.contents[d];
                                    output += 'contents<br>';
                                        for (var e = 0; e < product.tabs.tab.contents.content.length; e++) {
                                            var content = contents.content[e];
                                            output += 'content<br>';
                                                for (var f = 0; f < product.tabs.tab.contents.content.title.length; f++) {
                                                    var title = content.title[f];
                                                    var bodytext = content.bodytext[f];
                                                    output += '<h3>' + title + '</h3>';
                                                    output += bodytext;
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

        output += '</div>';

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop is not valid. as per the data in the link, `product.tabs` is not an array. its an object. so you can't really loop and object you need to have a different way to process that object.

```
for (var a = 0; a < object.product.length; a++) {
    var product = object.product[a];
    var name = product.product_name;
    output += '<h2>' + name + '</h2>';
    output += 'tabs<br>';
    var tabs = product['tabs']['tab'];
    for (var c = 0; c < tabs.length; c++) {
        var tab = tabs[c];
        output += 'tab<br>';
        var contents = tab['contents'] != undefined ? tab['contents']['content'] : [];
        output += 'contents<br>';
        for (var e = 0; e < contents.length; e++) {
            var content = contents[e];
            output += 'content<br>';
            var title = content.title;
            var bodytext = content.bodytext;
            output += '<h3>' + title + '</h3>';
            output += bodytext;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, back to school for me then. Any suggestions on how to set this up differently to get it up and running?

Comment: Updated the Answer.

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks a bunch!